# Grep expression to match space or start-of-line

Tags: regex, grep

I am looking for a grep expression which lets me check if there is a space or a start-of-line before a punctuation mark; I want to make sure that punctuation is used consistently.  What I have is this (for simplicity I replaced `[\.,;:\!?]` with just a `,` in the example):

```
~ > echo -e "some, text\nsome ,text\n,some text" | grep " ,"
2:some ,text
```

That's ok, but misses the third case.  I've tried `[^ ],` and `"(^\| ),"` but neither work.  What's the correct expression here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what'll work.  I don't think you can assume the -P option will be available (It's not in the default OSX grep).  But grep -E lets you avoid the escaping too:

```
echo -e "some, text\nsome ,text\n,some text" | grep -E "( |^),"
```

Comment: Thanks, the -E worked nicely (so did the -P of mohit6up's answer, as I use MacPorts).

Answer (score 1):

Try with a positive look-behind assertion using the `perl` flavour of `regex`:

```
echo -e "some, text\nsome ,text\n,some text" | grep -P '(?<=\s|^),'
```

That yields:

```
some ,text
,some text
```

Comment: That works, although above `-E` option was a simpler solution.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
`echo -e "some, text\nsome ,text\n,some text" | grep -P "( |^),"`

`-P` interprets it as a Perl-like regex that prevents unnecessary escaping of characters.