# using Regex and linux commands(grep or egrep?) to find specific strings

Tags: regex, linux, grep

**Note**: I am not sure that my regex's are correct since my textbook at school does not explain/teach regex's of this form but only of the math form such as for DFA's/NFA

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints

**Question:**

(a) find all occurrences of three letter words in text that begin with `a' and end with 'e';

(b) find all occurrences of words in text that begin with `m' and end with 'r';

**My Approach:**

a) `^[a][a-zA-Z][e]$`   (how to distinguish between 3 letter words and all words?)

b) `^[m][a-zA-Z][r]$`

Also I want to use these regex's in linux so would the following command work?:

```
grep '^[a][a-zA-Z][e]$' 'usr/dir/.../text.txt'
```

or should I use egrep in this way:

```
find . -text "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep '^[a][a-zA-Z][e]$'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the word boundary `\b` to match the start and the end of a word:

a)  find all occurrences of three letter words in text that begin with `a' and end with 'e';

```
grep -o '\ba[a-zA-Z]e\b'
```

The pattern matches a word boundary, then a following `a`, a single character and a following `e` and a word boundary.

b) find all occurrences of words in text that begin with `m' and end with 'r';

```
grep -o '\bm[a-zA-Z]*r\b'
```

The pattern matches a word boundary, an `m` zero ore more characters (thorugh the `*` quantifier), an `r` and a word boundary again.

---

Further I'm using the options `-o` which outputs every match on its own line rather than outputting the whole line of input which contains a match.

---

Btw, thanks to the option `-w` - matching only whole words - you can even simplify the above patterns to:

a)

```
grep -wo 'a[a-zA-Z]e'
```

and b)

```
grep -wo 'm[a-zA-Z]*r'
```

Thanks to @anubhava!

---

You asked for `egrep`. `egrep` can't help to simplify or optimize the patterns. `grep` is absolutely fine.

Comment: How would I be able to use this on the file I want? The file is text.txt so should it be grep -oi '\ba[a-z]e\b' /cs/dept/course/2014-15/W/201/text.txt ?

Comment: Ok, thats odd when i use the command "grep -oi '\ba[a-z]e\b' text " it doesn't throw any errors but when i enter it nothing happens.

Comment: The first pattern is simply not found in the text. The second pattern finds 3 occurrences of `microcomputer`. Add the word `are` to the text and the first command will find it.

Comment: Just checked that now, looks like it's working thanks for the help. Appreciate other people posting answers too.

Comment: Well explained answer +1

Comment: You are welcome. Check the manpage of `grep` (and `egrep`). It contains a full reference about the options and the regular expression syntax of the commands.

Comment: Hi just wondering, if convert  "grep -o '\ba[a-zA-Z]e\b'" to egrep -o 'ba[a-zA-Z]eb'  would this be the correct conversion

Comment: It would be `egrep -o '\ba[a-zA-Z]e\b'` or `egrep -oiw 'a[a-z]e'` or simply `grep -oiw 'a[a-z]e'`. `egrep` can't simplify the pattern here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep -w` with an alternation of regex for both the matches:

```
grep -w 'a[a-zA-Z]e\|m[a-zA-Z]*r' file.txt
```

Comment: Never knew about `-w`. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `egrep` is extended `grep` and is the same as calling `grep` with option `-E`. Secondly, you don't need to use `find` and `xargs` in many cases as there is `-r` option that will search recursively in files within specified path.

Your regular expression fits basic (not extended) regular expression language supported by `grep`, therefore `egrep` is not needed.

I would simplify this to

```
grep -r '^a[a-zA-Z]e$' /usr/share/dict/
```

and this

```
grep -r '^m[a-zA-Z]*r$' /usr/share/dict/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, you're only going to match full lines with three characters, matching the letters you expect.

The '^' indicates the beginning of the line

The '$' indicates the end of the line

In order to pull out only three letter words you're going to have to match on some whitespace. For instance 
grep ' a[a-Z]e ' 'usr/dir/.../text.txt'

however this will miss all instances of three letter words at the beginning or end of your line

[here is an issue using egrep and grep to match whitespace/start of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478764/grep-expression-to-match-space-or-start-of-line)